# Spring boot error in main method due to org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication not found

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I followed the steps given over here https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-maven-project

My pom.xml

....

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-simple</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <parent>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>  
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>  
  </parent>
  <properties>  
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <start-class>com.sample.SpringBootSimpleApp</start-class> 
  </properties> 
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>  
    </dependency> 
  </dependencies>
 <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

My application class

```
package com.sample;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootSimpleApp {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.sample.SpringBootSimpleApp");
            SpringApplication.run(SpringBootSimpleApp.class, args);  
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Buid is fine i am able to generate the jar files, by Eclipse RunAs -> Maven Build.. with goals clean install

When i use eclipse run as java application i get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
    at com.sample.SpringBootSimpleApp.main(SpringBootSimpleApp.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

I am using eclipse neon.3, workspace configured with alternate jre - installed jdk 1.8, workspace compiler level at 1.8.

pls help in running the application class.

Comment: I'd guess that Maven has corrupted a jar file when it downloaded it. Try running `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` and then rebuilding your application

Comment: @AndyWilkinson thanks it worked, could you please post it as an answer !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that Maven has corrupted a jar file when it downloaded it. Try running `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` and then rebuilding your application